# Odoo 12 docker compose doesn't display mounted extra addons

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo, odoo-12

I'm in search to create an extra addons on my odoo.
I've created an addon, and I've set in my docker compose file to mount the folder containing my addon on a folder into my odoo docker image defining to read also this folder when odoo container starts.
The problem is that I don't see my extra addons into the addons list when I'm using odoo via browser.

I'm using odoo 12 docker image in docker compose

Inside `addons/` i have my extra addons and inside `config/` i have my `odoo.conf`

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:12.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

`odoo.conf`

```
[options]
addons_path = /mnt/extra-addons
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo
```

If I display the content of `addons` I see:

```
$ ls addons/
custom-addon
```

`custom-addon` contains:

```
$ ls custom-addon/
controllers  demo  __init__.py  __manifest__.py  models  security  views
```

In a odoo log I read that `/mnt/extra-addons` was read by odoo:

```
web_1  | 2019-08-02 13:45:12,691 1 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/var/lib/odoo/addons/12.0', '/mnt/extra-addons', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons']
```

If I access into container and i list the content of `/mnt/extra-addons`  I can see the content of my local addons folder mounted into container.

```
$ docker-compose run web bin/bash
odoo@1cb225a60e13:/$ ls mnt/extra-addons/
custom-addon
```

But I can't see my addons listed into the modules list on odoo

Answer (score 1):

Open Odoo in debug mode (either from Settings page or just modify the URL yourself) go to the Apps menu and proceed with "Update Apps List" menu. That will open a wizard. Just press the "Update" button. The wizard will Odoo tell to update the modules list/table (ir_module_module). Afterwards you should see them under Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the odoo container so that odoo will re-read the content of the addons folder. In case you changed the docker-compose yaml file to include it and forgot to restart after the edit.

```
docker-compose restart web
```

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same issue. It's not a bug, it's an issue with documentation. You will see new addons if you will switch on "Extra" in the Filters. Please check the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcP6b.png)